# Bad token exception on spinner which uses (android:entries="@array/type") in fragment

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-popupwindow

When I run my code on some devices (Like MI note 4) it gives me an exception:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7989790 is not valid; is your activity running?

But when I run this on a high speed and latest mobile (MI note 5 pro) it works fine. I can't understand the error here, please guide me thanks.

Here is XML for the spinner :-

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:entries="@array/type" />
```

and my string array:

```
<string-array name="type">
     <item>Every Month</item>
     <item>Every Year</item>
     <item>Once</item>
</string-array>
```

---

```
add_reminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.add_reminder, null);

        final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(view1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        pw.setFocusable(true);
        pw.setTouchable(true);
        pw.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


        final Spinner type = view1.findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);
});
```

My fragment is still running in behind a pop-up, so this error must not be appearing since it shows that activity is not running.
And remember it's running OK on latest device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that error by putting my `popup`'s XML code in fragment and make it visible on click. By that way `spinner`'s code runs nicely on every device that way **error must be somewhere in using spinner in custom popup.**

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.add_reminder, null);
```

To

```
View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_reminder, null);
```